# Edit a value grabbed by awk before committing to a file

Tags: bash, file, awk

I have the below awk command which grabs information from a file that is tab separated.

```
awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 $4 }' data.log >> data.json
```

The data contained in $4 is a full URL of which I only want the domain name and that can be retrieved using the below example

```
echo 'http://www.example.com/page?param=stuff' | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

Which would return www.example.com, however I only want example.com

I am looking for a way to combine these two statements (If possible) as well as the best solution to remove anything that comes before the example.com (Some URls will have www, some will have other text and some will have nothing)

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` function in `awk` for this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ split($4, a, "/"); sub(/^www\./, "", a[3]); 
             print $2 a[3] }' data.log >> data.json
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I understand, the split is using "/" as the delimiter so this is assuming that all my examples will have an http://? (Which is fine in this case, but just for documentation)

Comment: Yes it it true that split is using `/` as delimiter and assuming that a `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` etc are there in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit of a mess, but will extract everything between www. and the end of .com regardless of whether `/` or any other characters are used.

Hope it helps :)

`awk '{print substr($4,index($4,"www")+4,index($4,".com")-index($4,"www"))} 'data.log >> data.json`